# Why two inference models with similar mAP have quite different performance in deployment?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

Admin wants to ask Deep Learning queries at another site, but that site has no response. But I believe this question will be useful for those like me who train own network.

I have two inference models.
One is using VGG net and another one is my own network.
When training VGG net gave mean AP is 0.99

```
AP for vertical = 0.9999
AP for horizontal = 0.9847
AP for plate = 0.9981
Mean AP = 0.9943
```

I trained my own network and I had mean AP is 0.98

```
AP for vertical = 0.9946
AP for horizontal = 0.9688
AP for plate = 0.9879
Mean AP = 0.9837
```

It was close so the performance should be quite close.

When I test, inference trained with VGGNet is quite good. All objects are detected.

But for my own model, some objects are not detected.
My inference model was trained with Xavier initialization and VGGNet has pre-trained model.

What should I do next, since the two mAP are quite close, so I am expecting similar performance?

Comment: is it possible your model overfit the training data?

Comment: @Shai it is not overfitting. If overfitted, I won't detect anything. Now is there are detections, but at some points there are missing objects in detection. Not as good as trained model with VGGNet. Any way I can improve my model? should I pretrain with image net images?